# I have a script, in yii. That almost does the job, need just a little push

Tags: image, yii

I am not a programmer by any means. I purchased the script and have spent two weeks and many variations trying to get the code to do what I need.  It is 'almost' there.

```
<div id="step-2" style="position:absolute; center:overflow-y:;">
<?php if($images): ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $img => $data): ?>
<a href="javascript:;" class="pin-img">
<img src="<?php echo $img ?>"  />
</div>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2><?php echo Yii::t('yii', 'No relevant found!') ?></h2>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

It returns the images from a site.  It only lets me select the first image.  Even though all images are displayed.  Only one is actually clickable.  If I hover over each of the images I see the javascript href.  I understand that to be some sort of place holder.  that just makes the browser show the hand.

I just need the script to allow each item to be a choice for reaction.

```
http://silenceisnotawkward.com/Sinapin/Script/# is the live code.
```

I have made a test user

Test=user
Password =password in case anyone wants to see what the site does.
    `http://www.ew.com/ew/` is a good link to pin from website and see the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at your site, but looks like you are confusing your nesting of HTML tags, because you introduced a end-of-dev tag in your link.

```
<div id="step-2" style="position:absolute; center:overflow-y:;">
   <?php if($images): ?>
   <?php foreach ($images as $img => $data): ?>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="pin-img">
         <img src="<?php echo $img ?>"  />
         <!-- I removed the < / div > from here -->
      </a>
   :
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div
```

>

*HINT: I indented the code to make it more readable, Try doing the same with your code you posted and see where it leads you.*